# I get a "module 'imaplib' has no attribute 'IMAP4_SSL'" when I run my program like windows service

Tags: python, ssl, windows-server-2012-r2, imaplib

I've made a Windows Service with Python to read some mails and get some information.
When I use it in my win7 developer machine with Pycharm, it works well, but when I try to run it ln a windows 2012 server (that is where it will work), I receive "module 'imaplib' has no attribute 'IMAP4_SSL'"

The funny thing is that when I put the same commands in python's console in the server, it doesn't give me any error.

Code is:

```
    def open_imap():
        # Read the config file
        config2 = configparser.ConfigParser()
        config2.read(os.path.join('C:\\', 'IziPayMail.ini'))
        # Connect to the server
        hostname = config2.get('Mail', 'hostname')
        logging.info('Hostname = ' + hostname)
        connection = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(hostname)
        logging.info('Conectado a ' + hostname)

        # Login to our account
        username = config2.get('Mail', 'username')
        password = config2.get('Mail', 'password')
        connection.login(username, password)
        logging.info('Logeado a ' + username)
        
        return connection
```

Anyone has an ide about what can be happening?

Claudio

Comment: Does `import ssl` work?  It may not be able to find the SSL library, so it omits support for IMAP4-SSL.

Comment: Yes, import ssl works fine

Comment: I have installed pycharm in windows 2012 too and the script works well. It seems that the problem is only when It run as a service. I'll continue testing

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of trying, I have found that I have something to do with running it like a Windows Server. I also I've noticed that it have something about SSL.
I got tired and I change the protocol to a IMAP without SSL... Now It works.
I really would like to find a real answer to this, but using IMAP works for now.